# Rejeição de Edição - Forma de discussão com o revisor

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Recentemente verifiquei meu histórico de edições realizadas assim como suas análises. São poucas, e destas algumas foram rejeitadas, o que, acho totalmente normal. Mas o que não é normal é o motivo, que se repete a cada edição rejeitada. Uma destas frases prontas utilizadas nas edições rejeitadas é:

***Esta edição não faz a publicação mais fácil de ser lida, mais fácil de ser encontrada, mais precisa ou mais acessível. As mudanças são completamente supérfluas ou de fato prejudicam a legibilidade.***

Concordo que o tempo está cada vez mais precioso, no entanto, ele tem o mesmo valor para ambas as partes. Afinal o tempo de edição também deve ser valorizado. Quero aproveitar para dar os parabéns aos bons revisores, que evitam **"[gafes](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/gafe)"** e modificações desnecessárias, aos demais, desejo mais atenção e empenho, ou bom senso para deixar a avaliação para outro revisor. Assim, gostaria de chamar a atenção para esse assunto e esclarecer uma duvida:

Existe alguma forma de discutir as edições com os revisores?

Sem a intenção de realizar nenhum apontamento ou desrespeito, destaco algumas das sugestões rejeitadas recentemente:

1. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/72899
2. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/72707
3. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/72392
4. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/72173
5. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/71972

Comment: Entenda como criticas pra você melhorar: A **1** está com código a mais "aparentemente" que do que na pergunta original e sem explicação da origem. **2** parece superficial. **3** Além de código, tem texto que não foi o AP que escreveu e não tem explicação. **4** e **5** são totalmente superficiais e não melhoram nada de verdade.

Comment: Agradeço a todas as críticas, e sim, serão muito bem aproveitadas, @Guilherme Nascimento.

Comment: Uma dúvida: Que significa gafs ? Na sua frase "evitam gafs e modificações desnecessárias"

Comment: Ta ai uma [gafe](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/gafe),... faltou um "e"... vou corrigir. Obrigado...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pelo que vi nas edições, em algumas foram feitas alterações bastantes superficiais, ou seja, as alterações não melhoraram ou facilitaram a compreensão da postagem, e os revisores devem ter tido este mesmo pensamento, pois em todas as decisões parecem ter sido unânimes.

Já nas edições https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/72899 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/72392, houve uma alteração do conteúdo inicial, e este tipo de edição deve ser evitado, não se deve jamais alterar uma postagem adicionando informações que o autor não tenha citado em algum momento do post, ou remover/adicionar pedaços do código, se você viu algo no código que crê não está correto ou está incompleto, comente abaixo e alerte o autor quanto aos erros, para que ele mesmo atente-se ao problema e efetue a correção. Estas duas rejeições, ao meu ver, foram corretas.

Quanto a edição feita aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/72707, é um caso que eu até aprovaria, mas ai é critério pessoal de cada revisor.

É louvável que pessoas queiram sempre contribuir com o site, seja com respostas e perguntas, seja procurando melhorar o conteúdo já publicado, e aos poucos a gente vai aprendendo mesmo, e sempre que ficar em dúvida, você pode também ir no [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) e perguntar diretamente a outros membros, ou conversar diretamente com os próprios revisores, para esclarecer o que poderia ser melhorado para edições futuras.

Comment: Concordo 100%, acrescento que a http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/72173 introduziu um erro

Comment: Revi as duas primeiras e a(s) razão(ões) da rejeição são aqui bem explicadas pelo diegofm.

Comment: Obrigado diegofm, farei o uso do *chat*. Das edições **1** e **3**, depois de um comentário foram incorporadas pelo autor, como você mesmo sugeriu diegofm.

Comment: Minha intenção não era chamar a atenção para nada pontual, mas para o assunto de uma maneira geral, de qualquer forma grato pelas **adições** ao *post* @Math, foram super válidas e geraram um ótimo debate. Meu singelo obrigado a todos pela requintada atenção e pelas produtivas opiniões.